# How to automatically execute a javascript function from an external js file on page load with a specific condition

Tags: javascript, function, call

I am newbie in HTML and JS language, and i am finding the correct way to use JS function for this scenario.

> All i want to do is: displaying the `<div>` tag on page load, only if
>   the the "level" variable equals to a specific value, e.g. "0".

I found that the JS language is not really difficult to read, but maybe a little challenging to figure out how it works at first.
I really appreciate your suggestions.
I put the bone of the question below.

### Thank you so much :)

Importing external js file into JSP.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="class.js"></script>
```

---

The value that is from the JSTL EL:

```
<input type="text" name="level" value="${level}" />
```

---

The  tag that i want to make its attribute "display" change to "none".

```
<div id="class" style="display: none;">
<!-- CONTENT -->
</div>
```

---

external JS file, i dont know how to call this in JSP file to reach my purpose.

```
autoShow(target) {
    target.style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this function in the script file which loads after external JS files to make sure that DOM is already prepared as you need.

This self executing function will change display property immediately if input value is the one you need. You may use querySelectorAll() or getElementsByTagName() and iterate through other inputs as well.

```
(function () {
    var input = document.querySelector('[name="level"]');
    if (input.value === "0") {
        input.style.display = "block";
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i got it, and finding more quay to play with javascript.
So exciting :)